# Python underlying analysis books/articles?

Tags: python, performance, architecture, comparison

Does anyone know good books that discuss the underlying architectures, in-depth analysis of CPython implementation. Something like

- how list / tuple / dict implemented (and performance comparison...)
- OOP discussion in Python context

Sorry if it sounds like a silly question :(

Comment: Would the print out of sources suffice?

Comment: Would reading the source be good enough?

Comment: For me it's much easier and eye-opening to read people's analysis on source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should absolutely, at some point in your Python career, read every word of the [Python Data Model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) and the [Python Execution Model](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html).  While not CPython-specific, these articles are essential to understanding Python deeply.

Answer (score 3):

**Python features are described and discussed in [Python Enhancement Proposals ("PEPs")](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/)** These describe the implementation, also **PEPs often contain working Python Code to help explain the algorithm** though the final implementation may be in C. If you need more details than can be gotten from the PEPs then you should take a look at the source code.

Note: PEPs are written from the perspective of what ever enhancement is being proposed rather than an overall description of the implementation. So for example there might a PEP for Dict-Comprehensions but not for Dicts as a whole. **For a top down view of Python internals the source code is the place to go.**

Answer (score 2):

Beautiful Code book has a nice explanation about how dicts are implemented.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question but it's useful to know nevertheless:

The source code of CPython is well-written and well-documented, and there are some PEPs that shed light on parts of the implementation. You should really try just reading it.